# Converting LSTM model to tflite

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I'm facing an issue while converting the LSTM model to tflite.

I'm converting this model to use it in my flutter app.

The model is used to detect and translate Indian sign language.

Below is my conversion code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
model=load_model("action.h5")
tf.keras.models.save_model(model,'model.pbtxt')
converter =tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model=model)

lite_model=converter.convert()
with open("lite_model.tflite","wb") as f:
    f.write(lite_model)
```

If I run this code, the following error occurs

```
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model.pbtxt\assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: model.pbtxt\assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: C:\Users\gk\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6276n3rh\assets
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: C:\Users\gk\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6276n3rh\assets
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConverterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [73], in <cell line: 7>()
      4 tf.keras.models.save_model(model,'model.pbtxt')
      5 converter =tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model=model)
----> 7 lite_model=converter.convert()
      8 with open("lite_model.tflite","wb") as f:
      9     f.write(lite_model)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py:929, in _export_metrics.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    926 @functools.wraps(convert_func)
    927 def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    928   # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 929   return self._convert_and_export_metrics(convert_func, *args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py:908, in TFLiteConverterBase._convert_and_export_metrics(self, convert_func, *args, **kwargs)
    906 self._save_conversion_params_metric()
    907 start_time = time.process_time()
--> 908 result = convert_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    909 elapsed_time_ms = (time.process_time() - start_time) * 1000
    910 if result:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py:1338, in TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2.convert(self)
   1325 @_export_metrics
   1326 def convert(self):
   1327   """Converts a keras model based on instance variables.
   1328 
   1329   Returns:
   (...)
   1336       Invalid quantization parameters.
   1337   """
-> 1338   saved_model_convert_result = self._convert_as_saved_model()
   1339   if saved_model_convert_result:
   1340     return saved_model_convert_result

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py:1321, in TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2._convert_as_saved_model(self)
   1317   graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors = (
   1318       self._convert_keras_to_saved_model(temp_dir))
   1319   if self.saved_model_dir:
   1320     return super(TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2,
-> 1321                  self).convert(graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
   1322 finally:
   1323   shutil.rmtree(temp_dir, True)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py:1131, in TFLiteConverterBaseV2.convert(self, graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
   1126   logging.info("Using new converter: If you encounter a problem "
   1127                "please file a bug. You can opt-out "
   1128                "by setting experimental_new_converter=False")
   1130 # Converts model.
-> 1131 result = _convert_graphdef(
   1132     input_data=graph_def,
   1133     input_tensors=input_tensors,
   1134     output_tensors=output_tensors,
   1135     **converter_kwargs)
   1137 return self._optimize_tflite_model(
   1138     result, self._quant_mode, quant_io=self.experimental_new_quantizer)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert_phase.py:212, in convert_phase.<locals>.actual_decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    210   else:
    211     report_error_message(str(converter_error))
--> 212   raise converter_error from None  # Re-throws the exception.
    213 except Exception as error:
    214   report_error_message(str(error))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert_phase.py:205, in convert_phase.<locals>.actual_decorator.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    202 @functools.wraps(func)
    203 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    204   try:
--> 205     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    206   except ConverterError as converter_error:
    207     if converter_error.errors:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py:794, in convert_graphdef(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, **kwargs)
    791   else:
    792     model_flags.output_arrays.append(util.get_tensor_name(output_tensor))
--> 794 data = convert(
    795     model_flags.SerializeToString(),
    796     conversion_flags.SerializeToString(),
    797     input_data.SerializeToString(),
    798     debug_info_str=debug_info.SerializeToString() if debug_info else None,
    799     enable_mlir_converter=enable_mlir_converter)
    800 return data

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py:311, in convert(model_flags_str, conversion_flags_str, input_data_str, debug_info_str, enable_mlir_converter)
    309     for error_data in _metrics_wrapper.retrieve_collected_errors():
    310       converter_error.append_error(error_data)
--> 311     raise converter_error
    313 return _run_deprecated_conversion_binary(model_flags_str,
    314                                          conversion_flags_str, input_data_str,
    315                                          debug_info_str)

ConverterError: C:\Users\gk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py:1325:0: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op requires element_shape to be static during TF Lite transformation pass
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
C:\Users\gk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\save.py:1325:0: error: failed to legalize operation 'tf.TensorListReserve' that was explicitly marked illegal
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
<unknown>:0: error: Lowering tensor list ops is failed. Please consider using Select TF ops and disabling `_experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops` flag in the TFLite converter object. For example, converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]\n converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False


!python --version
​
```

It throws a error in the converter.convert().
I'm new to deep learning and i have tried many other ways but it  resulted in the same error.

If this error cannot be solved, please suggest me what can I do.....is there any other model that can be used to detect sign language efficiently and can also be used in flutter apps.

Comment: I get the same error when trying to convert a simple model with just one LSTM layer. This used to work in an older TF version, I am sure.

Comment: Please share your model summary and the version of Python and TensorFlow in your env.

Answer (score 0):

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model_save/best.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
 converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
 converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
   tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
   tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
 ]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open("best63.tflite", 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

i use this,this is work!

Comment: Can you briefly explain the solution?